# How to change linetype in the legend with ggcuminc?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I am trying to manually work with `color` and `linetype` using `ggcuminc()`. As an example:

```
library(ggsurvfit)
library(tidycmprsk)

# Create an additional categorical variable to include
df_lung$age_cat <- ifelse(df_lung$age > 63, "GT63", "LTE63")
df_lung$status <- factor(df_lung$status)

# Default
cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + age_cat, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggcuminc(size = 1.5)
```

I would like to group the line colors by sex and line types by age category. I tried:

```
cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + age_cat, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggcuminc(size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "black", "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "solid", "dashed", "dashed"))
```

which gets the color to change, but not the linetype. After looking at the ggcuminc(), I found that specifying `linetype_aes` is reflected in the plot, but is not reflected in the legend.

```
cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + age_cat, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggcuminc(size = 1.5,
           linetype_aes = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "black", "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "solid", "dashed", "dashed"))
```

I then tried using the `guide` options in `scale_linetype_manual` to no avail.

```
cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + age_cat, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggcuminc(size = 1.5,
           linetype_aes = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "black", "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "solid", "dashed", "dashed"),
                        guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "solid", "dashed", "dashed"))))
```

The data for the plot can be viewed by

```
mydata <- cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + age_cat, data = df_lung)$tidy
View(mydata)
```

And I can see that the `strata` column contains the four unique combinations of sex and age category. Is there a way to work with this setup to get the desired legend. I suppose I could create new columns to reflect sex and age category and then build my own ggplot using `geom_step`, but it would be nice to just be able to specify what I want within `ggcuminc()`.

Comment: Using `linetype_aes=TRUE` works fine for me. Perhaps try with `+ theme(legend.key.width = unit(10, "mm"))` to see a dashed line instead of just a "short" line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd3JF.png

Comment: You are correct -- it is showing up in the legend, I just wasn't seeing it due to the width.